# Last Word not break avoid automatically

Tags: luatex, line-breaking, automation, luacode

I have need to avoid last word break. It must print in PDF before the line or break with previous word.

My MWE IS:

```
\documentclass{book}
\doublehyphendemerits=100000 
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
sample = [[
<datas>
<p>The investigations of cylindrically symmetric spacetimes can be traced back as far as to 1919 when Levi-Civita (LC) discovered a class of solutions of Einstein&#x2019;s vacuums field equations, corresponding static cylindrical spacetime referring [218]. The extension of the LC spacetimes to the stationary one was independent by Lanczos in 1924 [213] and Lewis in 1932 [219]. In 1925, Beck studied a class of exact solutions and interpreted them as representing the propagation of cylindrical gravitational waves (GWs) [24]. This class of solutions was later rediscovered by Einstein and Rosen in their seminal work on the studies of the nonlinearity of GWs in 1937, and in the same year van Stockum solved the problem of a rigidly rotating infinitely long cylinder of dust, and found explicitly the corresponding metric. In 1957, Bonnor and Weber and Wheeler studied the Einstein&#x2013;Rosen waves in great details, since then, cylindrically symmetric spacetimes [327, 328], have been extensively investigated with various motivations.</p>
</datas>]]
local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
tex.sprint(dom:query_selector("p")[1]:get_text())
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

My expect output result is:

[image]

Comment: do you have to do this in Lua? You could simply use `\mbox{various}~\mbox{motivations}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have need with `lua` or without `lua`, but automatically.

Comment: I would just increase the likelihood of a long last line rather than specifically prevent 1 word last line eg add `\parfillskip=0pt plus .7\textwidth` before setting the paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

The *Glisterings* column in **TUGboat** 28:2, 2007 shows several examples of controlling the shape of a paragraph. In particular for the purpose here is the definition of a paragraph where the last line is "not too short".

Following the declaration `\nottooshort`, as defined below

```
\newdimen\parabout
\newdimen\about
\about=2em
\newcommand*{\nottooshort}{%
\parabout=\hsize
\advance\parabout -\about
\leftskip=0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt
\rightskip=\leftskip
\parfillskip=\parabout minus \parabout
\parindent=2em }
```

then the last lines of paragraphs will be at least approximately `\about` long.

As examples:

```
% nottooshortprob.tex  SE 579338
\documentclass{article}

    \newdimen\parabout
    \newdimen\about
    \about=2em
    \newcommand*{\nottooshort}{%
    \parabout=\hsize
    \advance\parabout -\about
    \leftskip=0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt
    \rightskip=\leftskip
    \parfillskip=\parabout minus \parabout
    \parindent=2em }

\begin{document}

\about=2em
\nottooshort
 A paragraph where the last line is not too short. But we need some more text
to make the paragraph somewhat longer in the sense that it has more lines. 

\about=3em
\nottooshort
 A paragraph where the last line is not too short. But we need some more text
to make the paragraph somewhat longer in the sense that it has more lines. 

\end{document}
```

[image]